# How to automatically respond to an e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to automatically respond to an e-mail with some information.  The idea is to provide a self-service way for students to get grades and passwords.  I see sample scripts that work on e-mails, but I need to:

1. look for a keyword in the subject to understand what type of information to provide (i.e., grade, password, etc.)
2. look at the e-mail of the inbound e-mail to identify the student (optionally locate a password)
3. look up the information (possibly in a spreadsheet)
4. create an e-mail and send it to the student

I am more familiar with using scripts with e-mail and spreadsheets, but I would prefer to create this on a Google Sites page or embed it in a wiki.

Thanks in advance for the help,
JDF

Comment: No. This is a bad idea and ripe for abuse, not to mention the potential FERPA violations

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much detail you were looking for, or if you where looking for example code, but here are some high level things to think about.

1. First, if you are going to embed the code into a webpage that you want be able to access all your other Google things easaly. eg if i stored all the student names passwords and student numbers in an spreadsheet or database you have to set up permission to do so. Your website does not count as you "persay" because if you had it shared out then someone could potentally steal all your google stuff.
2. Take a good look through the Google appi [google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail). You can search your email by thread (subeject) and then go through the emails like that. I think all the function that you want are there.